# Preserve HTML elements in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML:

```
<application>
    <documentation>Before text.
        [This|http://google.com] is a link.
        Click [here|http://google.com] for another link. 
        After text.
    </documentation>
</application>
```

I want to replace new lines with `<br/>` tags and create links. The outcome should produce the following HTML:

```
Before text.<br/>
<a href="http://google.com">This</a> is a link.<br/>
Click <a href="http://google.com">here</a> for another link.<br/>
After text.
```

I have the XSLT below with the appropriate templates. My problem is that the `<br/>` elements added by the first function are stripped out by the second function. I've tried using an identity transform, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

My current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="application">
        <p>
            <xsl:variable name="with_new_lines">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-newlines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="documentation"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#xA;'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'new_line'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:variable name="with_links">
                <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$with_new_lines"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$with_links"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replace-newlines">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xA;')">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-newlines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Changing [here|http://a.com] to <a href="http://a.com">here</a>and
        [http://a.com] to <a href="http://a.com">http://a.com</a>-->
    <xsl:template match="*" name="create-links">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'http')">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,'[')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="the_link_and_after">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,'[')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="the_link">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link_and_after,']')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($the_link,'|')">
                        <xsl:variable name="the_url">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($the_link,'|')"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <a href="{$the_url}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link,'|')"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <a href="{$the_link}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$the_link"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <!--<xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,']')" />-->
                <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,']')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that each of your named templates creates a *result-tree-fragment*, containing a mixture of text nodes and elements (either `<br>` or `<a>`). When you send the result to be processed **as a string** by the other template, only the text nodes survive the treatment.

I would suggest you start by tokenizing the input into lines **as elements**. Then send each line in turn to be processed by the other template:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="application">
    <xsl:variable name="lines">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-lines">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="documentation"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <p>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($lines)/line">
            <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize-lines">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xA;')">
            <line><xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,'&#xA;')"/></line>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-lines">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <line><xsl:copy-of select="$text"/></line>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-links">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'http')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,'[')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="the_link_and_after">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,'[')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="the_link">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link_and_after,']')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($the_link,'|')">
                    <xsl:variable name="the_url">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($the_link,'|')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <a href="{$the_url}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link,'|')"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <a href="{$the_link}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$the_link"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!--<xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,']')" />-->
            <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,']')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you could call the 2nd template from within the 1st one, for each line separately before returning it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="application">
    <p>
        <xsl:call-template name="create-lines">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="documentation"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-lines">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xA;')">
            <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text,'&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="create-lines">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-links">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'http')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,'[')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="the_link_and_after">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,'[')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="the_link">
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link_and_after,']')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($the_link,'|')">
                    <xsl:variable name="the_url">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($the_link,'|')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <a href="{$the_url}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($the_link,'|')"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <a href="{$the_link}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$the_link"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!--<xsl:copy-of select="substring-after($text,']')" />-->
            <xsl:call-template name="create-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,']')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: We implemented the second option and it worked perfectly. Thanks @michael.hor257k